# Spark Interactive/Adhoc Job which can take Dynamic Arguments for Spark Context

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a solution for interactive/adhoc spark job. I have some arguments that I need to pass to my Spark Job. This is fine, but I want to pass these arguments as selected by the user form the dropdown menu by the user.

So for e.g. the Spark-submit job looks something like below, with the following arguments "prod /opt/var/var-spark/application.conf vc FX yes yes yes".

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --class main.gmr.SparkGMR \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --verbose \
  --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/var/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/log4j.properties" \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/var/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/log4j.properties" \
  file:///opt/var/var-spark/var-spark-assembly-1.0.jar \
  prod /opt/var/var-spark/application.conf vc FX yes yes yes
```

Now I want to make this job always running because it caches many dataframes in memory which can be used for later analysis. But the problem is this job dies and the in-memory dataframes/views are not there any more.

Also, I want to submit different arguments to this job next time, so e.g. 
**"prod /opt/var/var-spark/application.conf sc dx yes yes yes"**.

**Approaches I tried:** I tried to use the **Livy API** /batches endpoint to submit my job with arguments but the job starts, does processing and then dies. /sessions endpoint is ideal choice but that does not allow me to submit the class name and the arguments parameters in the request header.

Also tried to use the **Spark Structured Streaming** with the following code to get to get the arguments from the dataframe, but it fails with the error below:

```
 val lines = spark.readStream
      .format("socket")
      .option("host", "localhost")
      .option("port", 4042)
      .load();

    import spark.implicits._;
    val words = lines.as[String].flatMap(_.split(",")).collect;   
    var a =  words(0);
    var b = words(1);
    var c = words(2);
    var d = words(3);
    var e = words(4);

    val wordCounts = words.groupBy("value").count();

    val query = wordCounts.writeStream
     .outputMode("complete")
      .format("console")
      .start()    
    query.awaitTermination()
```

**ERROR:**

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Queries with streaming sources must be executed with
>   writeStream.start();; textSocket  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:196)

I want to get the arguments in the a, b, c, d, e from the above code and then I can pass the dynamic arguments for the queries that run in my job.

Any clues and other approach would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: any solution to the above problem?

Comment: You want to apply the parameters on the fly ? as long as the spark streaming job is running ?

Comment: Yes. Spark Streaming or any other solution. My code for Spark Streaming is not working above. Any code example to get the   var a =  words(0);
    var b = words(1);
    var c = words(2);
    var d = words(3);
    var e = words(4); values would be useful

Comment: I am also trying to follow this similar post https://medium.com/@anicolaspp/apache-spark-as-a-distributed-sql-engine-4373e254e0f9 and trying to create a interactive Spark Session. But not able to import the required libraries from  import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2